# How to access and modify global variables in python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am new to classes in Python. I was trying to write a linked-list program where I needed a global variable to do the counting of number of nodes instead of a function.
So, when I did as follows:

```
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0
```

Then outside the linked list class I was unable to access this self.count (in the part where I created the object of this class etc.) I thought that since it is a local variable to this class I was getting the error.
So, I tried this:

```
count = 0
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        global count
        self.count=0
```

I was thinking that if I made the global variable a datafield of this class, then I don't need to write:

```
global count
```

in every function under this class.
But outside the class whenever I am accessing count, it's value is zero.
Can someone please help.

Edit: The display function doesn't need this count so I can see my list being created perfectly. I just want to access the number of nodes using count outside the class so that I can check for position validity before calling insert or delete functions, etc.
I am attaching the snippet where it is giving me error, if it helps:

```
pos = int(input("Enter the position : \n"))
if (pos>(count+1))or(pos<1):
    print("Invalid Position")
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to make a global variable in the class instead you can make a  `self.[variable name]` however for changing the variable value you can `self.[var name] = [new value]`
for example :

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 1

classvar = myclass();
print(classvar.counter)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Elhadede, it solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the meaning of the keyword `global`. `global` is used when you want to access / modify a variable which was defined in the normal script, not in the function, e.g.

```
#test.py
c = 1

def test1():
    c = 3 #this will not modify the c which we declared earlier

test1()
print(c) #will print 1

def test2():
     global c #this tells the interpreter to look for the previously defined c
     c = 3
test2()
print(c) #will print 3
```

Now to access members of an object, you just need to use `objectname.variablename`

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual to use global inside a class. To access your class property, you just need to instantiate a new object.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
    self.color = 'red'
    self.number_of_door = 5

# let's say I want to get the number of doors and plus one for Toyota

Toyota = Car()
print(Toyota.number_of_door + 1)
```